# Sort by custom alphabet

Tags: code-golf, sorting

The challenge is to make a program that sorts a list of words, only that the words need to be in the order of a random given alphabet.

Your program will accept a string of comma-separated words and a new alphabet.
Your program will output every word in the same way in the new sorted order.

### Example:

Input:

```
home,oval,cat,egg,network,green bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzaeiouy
```

Output:

```
cat,green,home,network,egg,oval
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the winner is the person with the shortest program.

This is my first challenge so any improvements to the question/challenge are appreciated.

Comment: 1. I take from your example that the alphabet will be separated from the words by a space. Is that correct? 2. Will the words always be in lowercase?

Comment: @Dennis yes to both

Comment: That is a mistake. I will edit that.

Comment: +1 OK question (for a first try ;-)).  But I'm not seeing the relevance of the title - perhaps you can rename it to `Sort by custom alphabet` or something more creative?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yeah that might be better. I tried to play a little with the words. I aimed for a reference to ascii and utf-8 and the like to ask which it is. But that one failed. I'll change it to your suggestion which was better.

Comment: May we take the inputs in a form that is more appropriate to the language? E.g. two separate inputs; a character matrix with one word on each line, and a character vector of letters. A list of strings. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, <s>26</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
rr:A;',/{Af#}$',*
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Test case

```
$ cjam sort.cjam <<< 'home,oval,cat,egg,network,green bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzaeiouy'
cat,green,home,network,egg,oval
```

#### How it works

```
rr                    " Read two whitespace-separated tokens from STDIN. ";
  :A;                 " Save the second token (the alphabet) in A.       ";
     ',/              " Split the remaining token at commas.             ";
        {Af#}$        " Sort by the chunks' characters' indexes in A.    ";
               ',*    " Join, separating by commas.                      ";
```

Comment: Well, since u also made used the same approach, mine doesn't really make any sense now.

Comment: @Optimizer: You beat me by eight seconds. If you undelete your answer, I'll roll mine back.

Comment: No, I think its a trivial and very obv change. I should have looked at your updates before posting my answer in the first place :)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+coreutils, 37 bytes

```
tr ,$2 \\na-z<<<$1|sort|tr \\na-z ,$2
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./alphasort.sh home,oval,cat,egg,network,green bcdfghijklmnpqrstvwxyzaeiouy
cat,green,home,network,egg,oval, $
```

Comment: Nice way of dealing with the commas!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 characters

```
j\,o_mx_zdNchczd\,
```

**Test:**

```
$ pyth -c "j\,o_mx_zdNchczd\," <<< 'home,oval,cat,egg,network,green bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzaeiouy'
cat,green,home,network,egg,oval
```

**Explanation:**

```
                            Implicit: d=" "
                            Implicit: z=input()
j\,                         ",".join(
   o                                 order_by(lambda N:
    _                                                  rev(
     m                                                     map(lambda d:
      x_zd                                                              rev(z).index(d),
      N                                                                 N),
    chczd\,                                            z.split(" "[0].split(",")
```

Essentially, it sorts the chunks, with a key of the list of indexes of the characters in the string, then joins them on commas. The reversal businesses is shorter than spliting the string again.

Comment: 18 bytes: `j\,_omx_zdNchczd\,`

Comment: @Dennis very clever, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
function(w,a,`[`=chartr)"a-z"[a,sort(a["a-z",w])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdRDoMgDADQqyx8QdIdwZMQEztWwIngShXn5dmyvK/H3Q/d79nJXLJugDDZaXARWdgovF/KItTCotH@C200Y/eakq7CdUuzaBXLSlAOTOBQgEKATNIKLxCYKCv4MQZu6uGePsTXkta8vbnK0c4LaS77R5n@BQ)

Translates words from given alphabet to `a-z`, then sorts and then translates back.

Uses flexible I/O rules (vector of words and alphabet as string).

---

With strict I/O rules it goes up by a lot ([R](https://www.r-project.org/) is not very good with strings):

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 112 bytes

```r
function(s,`/`=strsplit,t=el(s/" "))paste(chartr("a-z",t[2],sort(chartr(t[2],"a-z",el(t[1]/",")))),collapse=",")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBDoIwEEDRq5Cu2mQM0X1PQkiodVqQ0tbpAMrlETVu38@n3endzdHykKIs0NWdLkwlh4GBNQZZalEJpbIpjNL2hpikMKdNADeXFkoi/vMXfu0YuTm3tYDjVQpsCsHkgvoDu5OiTxNCWkwAaxjQe4jIa6IRPCHG6mpvzvf3MUwxP6jwsj43g0OaX8f/Bg)

Here we do the splitting of the input string inside the function.
First, we redefine `/` to be `strsplit`. It always returns a list, so we will need to extract the first element (which is shortest done by `el`). We split the words from the alphabet on   and then the words themselves on `,`.
Then we do the same trick as in the main answer.
At the end we collapse the whole vector with `,` using `paste`.

---

With many strange function redefinitions:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 111 bytes

```r
function(s,`?`=el,`[`=chartr,`/`=strsplit,t=?s/" ")paste("a-z"[t?2,sort((t?2)["a-z",?(t?1)/","])],collapse=",")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDsIgEAC/0nCCZE2jd8JDGhMQF1pLAWHbaj9fibeZSaacTp5ujZamFHkFrbTEAHrQ0o6mUAHda1mp1BwmApKq9qxjIptKyJm5HGwgdYOaCnHeSAz/CKrJVfQM2F3cwaYQTK4om4vTcTamBSFtJoA1BOg9RKQ9lRl8QYzdwz6dH19zWGJ@l0rb/jkMTmn9tv8H)

Here we also redefine `[` to be `chartr`, so we cannot use `[` to subscript `t` anymore, but we can use `el` for this purpose.
This leads us also to redefining `?` to be `el` (after some trial and error with operator precedence). It is worth noting, that `?` can act as binary and unary operator and has the lowest precedence of all.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 23 bytes

```
{","/x@<y?x:","\x}." "\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJwNxksOQDAQANB9T9HMesJeJNwDi6ppfVuqaIm781ZPZQ8gpKHMYxGyv3V4E+BQM6Yq6O1CaE8xoxQeSWs05C/rJtSOyPBWdkr34zQvZt3c7s8r3IIGe0Ro2Acq1B9E)

Takes input as outlined in question.

- `" "\` split input on the space, into the list of comma-delimited words and the (shuffled) alphabet
- `{...}.` call the function with the list of words as the first arg (`x`) and the alphabet as the second arg (`y`)
- `x:","\x` split the string of comma-delimited words into a list of the words themselves, updating the `x` variable
- `y?x` look up the index of each character in each word in the shuffled alphabet
- `x@<` grade the resulting list of lists of indices, and apply the sort order to the list of words
- `","/` join the individual words with commas

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
{x@<y?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qucLCptK+o5eJKi9ZQysjPTVWyVsovS8wBUsmJJUAyNT0dSOallpTnF2UDWelFqal5SprWSknJKWnpGVnZObl5BYVFxSVl5RVViamZ+aWVSrEADJ8efg==)

Assumes more lenient input/output format; a first arg `x` of a list of words, and a second arg `y` containing the shuffled alphabet. A list of strings is returned instead of a comma-delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```
a,b=$*
$><<a.split(?,).sort_by{|w|w.tr b,'a-z'}*?,
```

I'm using Ruby's `tr` to replace the custom alphabet with `a-z` before sorting. Input is via command-line argument.

Comment: You can shave off a byte if you use `$><<` to print to screen (you can remove the space then). You can shave off another two bytes by assigning `$*` to variables like so: `a,b=$*` and using `#sort_by` instead of `#sort_by!`.

Comment: @britishtea Thanks. I thought I would need `*$*` (which I had at first and which is the same length).

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>115</s> 50 bytes

Oh, an edit five years later :D And actually in the past I out-golfed myself, now I used `(map char(range 97 123))` to generate the `a - z` sequence but my original answer just re-uses the alphabet input via `(sort %2)`. Well this new answer requires a more liberal input format, namely the first argument is a list of words.

```
#(map(fn[i](str(mapv(zipmap %2(sort %2))i)))%)
```

I had to re-discover that vectors don't sort neatly, but this can be avoided by casting them to strings. And not by using `clojure.string/join` or `apply str`, they sort just fine as string representations of the vector! Change the `sort-by` to `map` and you get:

```
(def f #(map(fn[i](str(mapv(zipmap %2(sort %2))i)))%))

(f ["home", "oval", "cat", "egg", "network", "green"] "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzaeiouy")

("[\\f \\x \\j \\v]"
 "[\\x \\q \\u \\i]"
 "[\\b \\u \\p]"
 "[\\v \\e \\e]"
 "[\\k \\v \\p \\r \\x \\n \\h]"
 "[\\e \\n \\v \\v \\k]")
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoMgEIXhvaeY0JjMJO2m1zEuUAdEESiiVi9PpavvX7y83vppi5wzDqxAwQNXH9OrO1G5xrS4poiLDDteJtxC/f4PbokMEdVEVVVhiMYl6wAVNGL0C4snCL9LW@xlKrDWBcfp8HEuqSOzEy2Irh@UHqfZLi584pr243tJNn47xf2f8w8)

**Original answer:**

```
#(apply str(butlast(interleave(sort-by(fn[w](apply str(map(zipmap(sort %2)%2)w)))(re-seq #"[a-z]+"%))(repeat \,))))
```

Wow, this started of well with `(sort-by(fn[w](mapv(zipmap(sort %2)%2)w)))` but then I realized `vec` don't get sorted the same way as strings, and interleaving those commas takes significant amount of code as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#`U',¡ΣXsSk}',ý
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fOSFUXefQwnOLI4qDs2vVdQ7v/f8/Iz83VSe/LDFHJzmxRCc1PV0nL7WkPL8oWye9KDU1TyEpOSUtPSMzKzsnN6@gsKi4pKy8oioxNTO/tBIA)

With less restricted I/O rules, this could have been **2 (or 3) [bytes](https://tio.run/##LczNDYAgDIDRu2P0zEaEA2pFREHB/3Xcx5WwNhxewkfThqRrizm/j8tZSuhBQCATQVBCcu1Ek5F/mlIrF9LLsL887/0zAUe5FYnjqSmFhQelqrppO9PbwY2Tn5eY1v04b402bNcH)**:

- `Σk`: [Try it online with character-list input](https://tio.run/##LczNDYAgDIDRu2P0zEaEA2pFREHB/3Xcx5WwNhxewkfThqRrizm/j8tZSuhBQCATQVBCcu1Ek5F/mlIrF9LLsL887/0zAUe5FYnjqSmFhQelqrppO9PbwY2Tn5eY1v04b402bNcH);
- `ΣSk`: [Try it online with string-list input](https://tio.run/##Dca7FYAgDEDR3jFSu42lxwIwIvKJAoK6jvu4UqS571ES0iDz9w6WeYSVPEIPVIRrUSI3UetmwFwp2nY6IgaYOqnmRa9ms86H/Ygpl3o9Ag2d9w8).

**Explanation:**

```python
#            # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces
 `           # Pop and push both strings separated to the stack
  U          # Pop the alphabet-string, and store it in variable `X`
   ',¡      '# Split the words-string on ","
      Σ      # Sort this list of words by:
       X     #  Push the alphabet-string `X`
        s    #  Swap so the current word is at the top of the stack again
         S   #  Convert it to a list of characters
          k  #  Get the index of each character in the alphabet-string
      }',ý  '# After the sort-by: join this list of words with "," delimiter
             # (after which this string is output implicitly as result)

Σ            # Sort the first (implicit) input-list of character-lists by:
 k           #  Index each character into the second (implicit) alphabet-string
             # (after which the sorted list of character-lists is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Technically, isn't [05AB1E newer](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/f437bfd9e04419c4a5208ccd91e30d97711d8d98) than the challenge?

Comment: @pajonk It is, but [since mid 2017 that doesn't matter anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12930/52210). Newer languages are allowed to answer challenges without adding a "non-competing".

Comment: thanks for the update, I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (E6) 102 <s>119</s>

Sort with a mapping function 'M' based on the alphabet in variable 'a'
*With IO using popup (prompt + alert)*

```
x=prompt().split(/[ ,]/),
a=x.pop(),
M=w=>[10+a.search(c)for(c of w)]+'',
alert(x.sort((a,b)=>M(a)>M(b)))
```

*As a (testable) function with 1 string parameter, returning a string array (92)*

```
F=x=>(
  M=w=>[10+a.search(c)for(c of w)],
  x=x.split(/[ ,]/),
  a=x.pop(),
  x.sort((a,b)=>M(a)>M(b))
)
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
F('home,oval,cat,egg,network,green zyxwvtsrqpnmlkjhgfdcbaeiou')
```

*Output*

```
["network", "home", "green", "cat", "egg", "oval"]
```

Comment: -4 if you replace your sort function with `(M(a)>M(b))-(M(a)<M(b))`

Comment: @DocMax very nice. It turns out that it's even simpler than that (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7232172/3640407)

Comment: If you reuse prompt for input and output and alias it you can avoid the split call by taking the inputs separately. I think that should save a few characters.

Comment: Also I'm only on my phone right now but why is M so complex? Wouldn't it work to use `M=w=>[...a].indexOf(w)`? I can't test it right now, unfortunately.

Comment: @IngoBürk w is a word, not a character. M replace each character in w with its position in a.

Comment: Ah, of course. Suddenly the 10 in there makes sense to me, too :) I don't know why I thought about characters..

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 131

```
w,a=input().split()
print(",".join(sorted(w.split(","),key=lambda s:"".join(["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[a.find(c)]for c in s]))))
```

There should be plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: You don't have to use a key as the sort function - just use the list of `a.find(c)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
b@?^_SKa^',J:',
```

Takes the two inputs as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE9GkAwDADQ41hyAgszo72@lIiiP6paXD7eCyaI6LZR49CjqqCrKxCR1VsCn/GACRMQMzhKxccdOBI5YIMuiZ7mhddtP6wLZ7xSLs@HZPz9/g)

#### Explanation

```lisp
b@?^_SKa^',J:',
       a         ; First command-line arg (list of words)
        ^',      ; Split on commas
     SK          ; Sort by the following key function:
   ^_            ;   Split the word into a list of letters
 @?              ;   Get the index of each letter in
b                ;   The second command-line arg (alphabet)
           J:',  ; Join the resulting list on commas
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸Îq, nU¸Ì q,
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uM5xLCBuVbjMIHEs&input=ImhvbWUsb3ZhbCxjYXQsZWdnLG5ldHdvcmssZ3JlZW4gYmNkZmdoamtsbW5wcXJzdHZ3eHphZWlvdXkiCi1R)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 24 bytes

```
tr $1 a-z|sort|tr a-z $1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY7SooUVAwVEnWraorzi0pqgFwgGygEkYaq2hetlJSckpaekZWdk5tXUFhUXFJWXlGVmJqZX1qpFLs_Iz83lSu_LDGHKzmxhCs1PZ0rL7WkPL8omyu9KDU1D2IIAA)

If we must use the OP's inane I/O format, 37 bytes:

```
tr $2, a-z\\n<<<$1|sort|tr a-z\\n $2,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwU274tQShYz83FSd_LLEHJ3kxBKd1PR0nbzUkvL8omyd9KLU1DyFpOSUtPSMrOyc3LyCwqLikrLyiqrE1Mz80sqlpSVpuhY3VUuKFFSMdBQSdatiYvJsbGxUDGuK84tKaoDiEDGQNETxAii1H2QrF8hWLqCtXEBbuaC2coFthSgDAA)

If a trailing comma is not allowed either, append `|head -c-1` for +10 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

With flexible input :

```python
lambda w,a:sorted(w,key=lambda s:[*map(a.find,s)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc29DoMgGIXh3aswLkhDunQz4Uqsw6d8oFV@ClRKb56WpNPz5izH5bhacyuS38sBehbQJgZDsD6i6BPbMfP/HobxosH1cJWbESzQiZbER7JajYS1xJ5wVBeIFVSqYjAm6/eayiMaMjXAu3kRUq2P/dDGPX2IZ3p/ADf7yl3TOL@Z2MvfO1Bavg)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

With strict input format :

```python
lambda x:sorted(x[:-27].split(","),key=lambda s:[*map(x[-26:].find,s)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lco9DoMgGADQ3VMYJ2jQwSZtQuJJrAPKB1L5K1DFXp526JufP9Pq7LWI4VE0MzNndabRhQQc5ZG2/X3qotcqoYY0mGxwDv8W6XgxzP9W29/o1AllOYl4wiUPzeoMELczTRaWCEhJLKTDhY3IAGDreeFCrs9NG@tfIab9yB8Gyr3Ppqp8UDYhgTLG5Qs)

Both can be shortened by 3 bytes in python 2 by removing `[*   ]` arround the `map`